# Default/correct context for HTML href attributes in Sightly

Tags: html, aem, sightly

I'm using Sightly and while investigating a bug in my application I noticed a behaviour I didn't expect.

Some of the links would render with ampersands in the query string escaped twice. Example:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com?a=1&amp;amp;b=2&amp;amp;c=3">
    link with explicit attribute context
</a>
```

Upon closer inspection, it turned out we had an `org.apache.sling.rewriter.Transformer` implementation escaping special characters in all `href` attributes running in AEM.

Coupled with Sightly XSS protection, this resulted in double escapes.

While investigating this further, I disabled the transformer and noticed a strange behaviour in Sightly itself.

### The attribute context and the default context in href attributes don't match

Given the following three elements, I'd expect them to render the `href` value in the same way (with the query string escaped, consistent with W3C standards)

```
<a href="${'http://www.google.com?a=1&b=2&c=3'}">no explicit context, expression used</a>
<a href="http://www.google.com?a=1&b=2&c=3">no explicit context</a>
<a href="${'http://www.google.com?a=1&b=2&c=3' @ context='attribute'}">
    explicit attribute context
</a>
```

However, only the last one performs the escaping and I get

```
<a href="http://www.google.com?a=1&b=2&c=3">no explicit context, expression used</a>
<a href="http://www.google.com?a=1&b=2&c=3">no explicit context</a>
<a href="http://www.google.com?a=1&amp;amp;b=2&amp;amp;c=3">
    explicit attribute context
</a>
```

For some reason, the the last one, using `context='attribute'` (the only one that does something with the `&` characters) escapes the ampersands twice, yielding invalid links.

This can be achieved with arbitrary element and attribute names so I think I can safely assume this is not some rewriter kicking in.

```
<stargate data-custom="${'http://www.google.com?a=1&b=2&c=3' @ context='attribute'}">
    attribute context in custom tag
</stargate>
```

Outputs:

```
<stargate data-custom="http://www.google.com?a=1&amp;amp;b=2&amp;amp;c=3">
    attribute context in custom tag
</stargate>
```

Furthermore, the [Display Context Specification](https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/sightly-spec/blob/master/SPECIFICATION.md#121-display-context) gave me the impression that the context, when rendering an attribute, would be picked up automatically as `attribute`

> To protect against cross-site scripting (XSS) vulnerabilities, Sightly automatically recognises the context within which an output string is to be displayed within the final HTML output, and escapes that string appropriately.

Is the observed behaviour here to be expected or am I looking at a potential bug in Sightly?

**Which context should I be using here? All contexts apart from `attribute` ignore the fact that query strings should be escaped in `href`. `attribute` on the other hand appears to be doing this twice. What's going on?**

I'm using *Adobe Granite Sightly Template Engine (compatibility)io.sightly.bundle   1.1.72*

### The uri context does not escape query strings in the way expected in HTML5 href attributes

I did also try using

```
<a href="${'http://www.google.com?a=1&b=2&c=3' @ context='uri'}">explicit uri context</a>
```

But it fails to escape the `&` chars, resulting in invalid HTML5.

```
<a href="http://www.google.com?a=1&b=2&c=3">explicit uri context</a>
```

Result of validation as HTML5:

> **Error Line 70, Column 35:** **& did not start a character reference. (& probably should have been escaped as &.)**
>
> `<a href="http://www.google.com?a=1&b=2&c=3">explicit uri context</a>`

### The html context correctly renders links with multiple query parameters in href attributes

It seems the only context I could possibly use here at the moment is `html` (`text` escapes `&` twice, just like `attribute`)

```
<a href="${'http://www.google.com?a=1&b=2&c=3' @ context='html'}">explicit html context</a>
```

yields

```
<a href="http://www.google.com?a=1&amp;b=2&amp;c=3">explicit html context</a>
```

Changing to this context would allow me to get the right value in the href, as rendered by the browser. However, it doesn't seem to have the correct semantics.

To quote [the description of the `html` context from the Sightly spec](https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/sightly-spec/blob/master/SPECIFICATION.md#121-display-context):

> Use this in case you want to output HTML - Removes markup that may contain XSS risks

Comment: What version of the `org.apache.sling.scripting.sightly` bundle do you have on your system? I suspect version 1.0.2, but just want to confirm this.

Comment: @RaduCotescu that is correct. We're using _1.0.2_, would an upgrade help?

Comment: No, the behaviour hasn't changed. For `src` and `href` attributes Sightly uses the `uri` XSS escaping context [0].

Comment: @RaduCotescu I see. I'll use `html` as a hack to make it work for now but I think this needs a wider discussion. I'll raise a ticket in the Sling Jira as soon as I have a moment to spare.

Comment: I think there's no need. I'll post an answer to your question since the comment field doesn't allow the full length of what I want to write.

Comment: @RaduCotescu excellent, thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106247/discussion-between-radu-cotescu-and-toniedzwiedz).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `src` and `href` attributes Sightly uses the `uri` XSS escaping context [1](https://github.com/apache/sling/blob/org.apache.sling.scripting.sightly-1.0.2/src/main/java/org/apache/sling/scripting/sightly/impl/html/dom/MarkupHandler.java#L405), [2](https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/sightly-spec/blob/1.1/SPECIFICATION.md#121-display-context).

Furthermore, the following markup is HTML5 valid using the validator from [3](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input+with_options):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="http://www.google.com?a=1&b=2&c=3">explicit uri context</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Can you please point me to the spec regarding HTML 5 query strings escaping for HTML attributes?

Comment: It didn't occur to me to question the validator. I'm using one deployed within our own infrastructure to avoid sending my client's markup outside secure networks. Good catch. I'll investigate further.

Comment: This was a bug in the validator we were using (we had it updated). Thanks again

Answer (score 4):

The `href` attribute uses the `uri` context rather than the `attribute` context. The `attribute` context is meant to be used for HTML attributes such as `title`, `id`, `data-*`, etc... Concerning your three examples:

```
<a href="${'http://www.google.com?a=1&b=2&c=3'}">link without explicit context, expression used</a>
<a href="http://www.google.com?a=1&b=2&c=3">link without explicit context</a>
<a href="${'http://www.google.com?a=1&b=2&c=3' @ context='attribute'}">link with explicit attribute context</a>
```

The first is using the `uri` context. The seconds isn't using Sightly at all. The third is misusing the `attribute` context.

The `unsafe` context should be avoided if at all possible.

Sightly doesn't currently escape the ampersand in the `uri` context as you would like. You should submit an Adobe Daycare ticket or contact the Apache Sling distribution list with your request.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'unsafe' context whenever everything else fails.

Comment: I can achieve the desired result with `attribute`, there's absolutely no need for me to resort to `unsafe`. I'm asking about the canonical way to render this kind of links and if the observed default behaviour is correct or erroneous.

Comment: I don't think there is anything canonical here. If 'url' doesn't work for you, use whatever works.

Comment: That's what I did for the time being. But I'd rather discuss this with the people who know Sightly better than me and consider an improvement over this approach and maybe an improvement to Sightly itself.